# После установки fedora linux по соседству с windows продолжает запускаться только windows

Tags: linux, windows, grub, install, dual-boot

В процессе установки новой системы fedora 26 beta я установил её на тот же диск, где и была windows(я немного отщипнул места от пространства с windows используя shrink). В системе 2 физических диска. После перезагрузки у меня как ни вчём не бывало запустился интерфейс выбора между windows 10 и windows 7(не grub). Размер второго диска уменьшился, значит linux создала себе раздел. Я посмотрел через Disk Manager, он есть, но ни названия нет, да и пишет, что 100% свободно. И да, он не bootable. Как теперь мне настроить так, чтобы при запуске я мог выбрать, что мне запустить - fedora или старый загрузчик windows 10 и 7.

Comment: а груб точно установили?

Comment: Сегодня ещё раз переустанавливал. Там точно был этап установки boot loader. Как и тогда, загрузочный раздел только один и он на другом диске, не туда, куда я систему ставил

Comment: надо выяснить, на uefi или нет устанавливается. (скорее всего на uefi). Если дисков (физических) много, установщик иногда может поставить загрузчик "не туда" (видел такое).

Comment: можете сделать запуск grub из boot-меню  windows, с помощью EasyBCD

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в bios и поставьте вашу fedora на первое место в Boot Priority. Также попробуйте выключить/включить secure boot. Если не поможет, снова загрузитесь с образа на флешке, примонтируйте уже установленные разделы и переустановите grub.